# Extract info from some cloumns, store into dataframe after flattening up

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one dataframe, my use case is to extract info from some columns do flattening up based on some column type and store into dataframe what is the efficient way to do and how ?

Ex: We have one dataframe which have lets say 5 columns for ex: a(string),b(string),c(string),d(json value),e(string). in transformation i wanted to extract or i can say flattened some records from d column (from json value). and in our resultant dataframe each value from json will become one row.

Comment: Can you add sample data and what you have tried

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi, i edits the question with exact requirement. please help me on the same.